# Remove line breaks, paragraph breaks in csv file using R

Tags: regex, r, csv, line-breaks

I have a csv file that contains some line breaks or paragraph breaks . How I know this is , when I open open this csv file in a word document I see the pilcrow symbol ¶, after the paragraph and before the beginning of the new paragraph. How do strip these line breaks from this csv file in R ? Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

PAST MEDICAL HISTORY

1. Persistent atrial fibrillation with atrial flutter, status-post atrial flutter ablation line in October of 2002.
2. Tachy/brady syndrome.
3. Insulin-dependent diabetes.  Has been diabetic for approximately 35 years.
4. Hypertension, well

Comment: I  gave it an upvote simply because it taught me a new term: `pilcrow` for `¶`. It does appear to me that in R you would be looking for lines of length equal 0 and simply excluding them. Will construct a test case, but next time please do post a plaintext example rather than an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an test case. You just want to remove empty lines. This is the file `test.txt` (complete with misspellings):
(Note: your example is clearly not a csv file.)

```
some header text

more text
 even omre text
```

## ------------------

```
 txt= readLines("test.txt")
 newtext <- txt[nchar(txt)>0]
 newtext
#[1] "some header text" "more text"        " even omre text"
```

To remove numbered lines (ones that begin with digits followed by a period) one would post process that result with sub():

```
 txt <- "PAST MEDICAL HISTORY

 1. Persistent atrial fibrillation with atrial flutter, status-post atrial flutter ablation line in October of 2002.
 2. Tachy/brady syndrome.
 3. Insulin-dependent diabetes.  Has been diabetic for approximately 35 years.  
 4. Hypertension, well"


 newtxt= readLines(textConnection(txt))
 sub("^[[:digit:].]+", "", newtxt)
#------------------------
[1] "PAST MEDICAL HISTORY"                                                                                             
[2] ""                                                                                                                 
[3] " Persistent atrial fibrillation with atrial flutter, status-post atrial flutter ablation line in October of 2002."
[4] " Tachy/brady syndrome."                                                                                           
[5] " Insulin-dependent diabetes.  Has been diabetic for approximately 35 years.  "                                    
[6] " Hypertension, well"
```

---

```
> sub("^[[:digit:].]+", "", newtxt[nchar(newtxt)>0])
[1] "PAST MEDICAL HISTORY"                                                                                             
[2] " Persistent atrial fibrillation with atrial flutter, status-post atrial flutter ablation line in October of 2002."
[3] " Tachy/brady syndrome."                                                                                           
[4] " Insulin-dependent diabetes.  Has been diabetic for approximately 35 years.  "                                    
[5] " Hypertension, well"
```

Comment: I'm going to need an example to understand what "bulleted" actually means. (And if this was useful .... it deserves an upvote.)

Comment: perfect Dust that worked, I got past that problem now the issues looks like the numbered bullets in text, wondering how I can get rid of those as well ?

Comment: I have updated my question with an example of bulleted text....right below the image

Answer (score 0):

The csv file by construction has line breaks at the end of each line, this way any parser can know when a line ends (so for example if you're writing csv file manually in Python you have to include the *\n* linebreak at the end. Try opening the csv file in R directly and inspect the content with head(your_file), you should see that it displays like you would expect.

Comment: This would be a good comment to the OP's question. There is also a really good chance the OP is talking about gosh-awful CSV files that actually span multiple lines due to the insanity of some programmer. OP hasn't provided more info.

Comment: @xv70 ,I opened the csv file in R, I dont see any `/n` I have uploaded an image right below my question.  This is a `$` separated csv file. Everything starting from start section id=21017 should be in one column. I want to get rid of those paragraph breaks between 21017........ and PAST MEDICAL HISTORY

Comment: You don't see any '\n' because they are used as line breaks and are not included in the character vectors constructed by R. Those 'pilcrow' characters/synbols/glyphs are not in the file either. They are being used by some editor to tell you where the line breaks actually are.

Comment: I have a file that has some additional line breaks (after cases, there should be ones) but within a variable "my [LINEBREAK] variable". Is there a way to fix that in R?